# Geom_rect starts from the final value of x axis R

Tags: r

I plotted a line graph and I separate them to different seasons. I separate them using geom_rect, but I faced a problem. The first season of the year is winter, and at the end of the year which is december is also categorised as winter. When I categorised the seasons using geom_point, the background color on the month of december is not changing. How can I make it change to purple which is the color for the background of winter season.
[image]

### Code

```
df<-data.frame(origin=c(data$origin),month=c(data$month), temp=c(data$temp))
df<-df%>%group_by(origin,month)%>%summarise(meanTemp=mean(temp))

rects <- data.frame(xstart = seq(0,9,3), xend = seq(3,12,3), 
                season = c('winter','spring','summer','autumn'))
ggplot() +
geom_rect(data = rects, aes(xmin = xstart, xmax = xend, ymin = 0, ymax = 30, fill = season), alpha = 
0.4) +
geom_line(df, mapping = aes(x=month,y=meanTemp,col=origin))+
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,12,by=1))+
scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(1,30,by=5))+
geom_vline(xintercept=3, linetype="dashed")+
geom_vline(xintercept=6,linetype="dashed")+
geom_vline(xintercept=9,linetype="dashed")+
geom_vline(xintercept=12,linetype="dashed")+
scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"))
```

### Structure of df

```
structure(list(origin = c("JFK", "JFK", "JFK", "JFK", "JFK", 
"JFK", "JFK", "JFK", "JFK", "JFK", "JFK", "JFK", "LGA", "LGA", 
"LGA", "LGA", "LGA", "LGA", "LGA", "LGA", "LGA", "LGA", "LGA", 
"LGA"), 
month = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), meanTemp = 
c(1.88086253369272, 
1.21803278688525, 4.19150943396226, 10.0792767732962, 15.1748655913979, 
21.0879166666667, 25.9638440860215, 23.2326558265583, 19.3876388888889, 
15.4455284552846, 7.29677419354839, 3.66937062937063, 2.19959568733154, 
1.3089552238806, 4.43140161725067, 11.1747222222222, 17.0833333333333, 
22.9591666666667, 27.0912516823688, 23.9156968876861, 19.9506944444444, 
15.9069105691057, 7.3671809256662, 3.76097902097902)), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), groups = structure(list(origin = c("JFK", "LGA"), .rows = 
structure(list(
1:12, 13:24), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Try `scale_fill_manual`.

Comment: @MagnusNordmo Isn't scale_fill_manual only change the color of a bar in bar chart?

Comment: You use fill to specify the colors inside `geom_rect` This is also true for bar charts. Can you supply some data so others can help you more easily? Try dput(df) for example.

Comment: @MagnusNordmo I have updated the structure of my data frame and I found that the month is repeating.